# Spring Boot - Web app is unable to stop MVStore writer thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using an embedded H2 database in my spring boot app but on every shutdown the database is not properly closed/dropped as I configured in `application.properties`. Here is the error that appears when I shut the application down:

```
2018-02-05 13:00:37.360 WARN  [localhost-startStop-2] [WebappClassLoaderBase] 
     The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a 
     thread named [MVStore background writer nio:C:/Users/user/testdb.mv.db] but has failed to stop it. 
     This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:2715)
```

The effect is that the file testdb.mv stays in my user directory and on a subsequent startup I get

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USERS(ID)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Users (id,first_name,last_name) VALUES (1,'Vincent', 'Vega') [23505-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
```

This is the `data.sql` script that is run on startup

```
INSERT INTO Users (id,first_name,last_name) VALUES (1,'Vincent', 'Vega');
```

This is the `User` entity which defines the `@Table("Users")`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

These are the h2 relevant configs in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none 
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE
spring.datasource.name=testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, which is telling the db not to close automatically, and `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE`. Change it to `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` if you want to have a persisted database with H2.

Comment: I tried with `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`, the "cannot shut down thread" error disappeared but the unique index error is still there. When I delete the `testdb.mv` file manually it works.

Comment: This happens because you have a `data.sql` which is used by Spring Boot to initialize the data, but it runs every time you start an app. This is useful for in memory dbs for testing purposes, that gets recreated on every start up. But you want to have a persistent database (which is not primary usecase for h2) and there for you need a different approach to initializing the data (liquibase, flyway..)

Comment: I'm trying to connect to MySQL, These configuration not helping, any more configurations needed?

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

configuration file, application.properties, this configs:

```
server.ssl.key-alias=***
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
```

were incorrect and the console didn't show the specific error.